# Type 'DefaultClient<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'ApolloClient<object>'

Tags: typescript, apollo, react-apollo, react-apollo-hooks

I am trying to explicitly supply a client to `useMutation`. Everything works fine except for the fact that typescript seems to see a type mismatch.

`Type 'DefaultClient<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'ApolloClient<object>'.`

The client is very similar to the one shown in apollo's [token authentication documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/networking/authentication/#header)

```
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { setContext } from 'apollo-link-context';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: '/graphql',
});

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  // get the authentication token from local storage if it exists
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  // return the headers to the context so httpLink can read them
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : "",
    }
  }
});

export const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
```

All I do really is import the client and supply it as an option to useMutation.

```
import {useMutation} from '@apollo/react-hooks'
import {client} from './client'

const MY_QUERY = `
  ...
`

const [myQuery] = useMutation(MY_QUERY, {
  client: client,
  onCompleted: () => {
    // do some stuff..
  }
})
```

useMutation seem to be expecting another type that the one that is inferred. How can I solve this mismatch ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you should have `InMemoryCache` as type parameter:

```js
export const client = new ApolloClient<InMemoryCache>({
```

I've tried to understand how this parameter is used, and I can't quite figure it out. Honestly, the empty object seems to work fine too:

```js
export const client = new ApolloClient<{}>({
```

But when reading the source code it looks like it wants the cache type.

Comment: Neither seem to work. In both cases the message does not go away.

Comment: Weird, I can reproduce your error, and it goes away when I use those types.

Comment: I must have done something wrong, it actually worked. My bad

Answer (score 0):

The `InMemoryCache` extends the `NormalizedCachedObject` shape. One instance where this shape is used to represent the Apollo cache in serialised form. https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/cache/InMemoryCache/#extract .

```
export const client = new ApolloClient<NormalizedCachedObject>({})
```